# FusionCharts Stacked 3D bar chart - Can you hide the 'base'?

Tags: fusioncharts

Kind of hard to describe, but I'm talking about the 'base' (not sure what else to call it) where the actual bars come out of.  I see no way to hide it in the properties (or change how it looks).

Is there any way to hide this, or at least change its appearance?  I've circled what I'm talking about in the image below:

[image: circled base]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'showCanvasBase' attribute of the  element to disable canvas base.

For ex-

```
<chart showCanvasBase='0' >
```

For more information on properties of the chart canvas, refer-

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/ChartSS/StackedBar3D.html#Anchor3